# Trapezoid and Simpson rule in Python?

Tags: python, integration, calculus

I have to write the trapezoid and simpson rule in python for the function `e^((-x)^2)`.

Here's what I got so far. The answer it gives out is `8218.7167913` but the answer according to my teacher is something like `1.77251356....`.

Where did I go wrong?

```
from numpy import *

def f(x):
    return e**((-x)**2)

def trapezoid(f, a, b, n):
    deltax = float(b - a)/(n)
    h = float(b - a) / n
    s = 0.0
    s += f(a)/2.0
    for i in range(1, n):
        s += f(a + i*h)
    s += f(b)/2.0
    return s * h

print trapezoid(f, -3, 3, 6)
```

Comment: what errors are you getting? If there's nothing wrong with your code, but you are getting the wrong answer, try printing out some intermediate values to see where the errors are in your logic.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your function: `e^((-x)^2)`.  The negative sign isn't doing anything because you're squaring it away immediately.  That seems strange.  More likely is that you were supposed to integrate `e^(-x^2)`.  Let's test:

```
>>> trapezoid(lambda x: e**((-x)**2), -3, 3, 1000)
2889.3819494560144
>>> trapezoid(lambda x: e**(-x**2), -3, 3, 1000)
1.7724146920763713
```